# client/server connection timed out

Tags: server, udp, client, coap

i am having an application running inside a gateway,
this application is a `coap-server` coded using the [libcoap](https://github.com/obgm/libcoap/) library

the server is running perfectly fine, the ip:port is tested using different commands such as `nmap` , `telnet` and others, each time it shows that the port is open and the connection is a success.

My problem is that there's no response from the server, wireshark is showing that the requests are being re-transmitted until timeout.

After some research, i thought that the gateway doesn't support `NAT loopback`, so i tried sending requests from another connection (i used my phones 4G). I even disabled firewall on the gateway too, But no success either.

**UPDATE**:

after some digging, i managed to receive a response from the server, but only when using TCP connection, the UDP still sends requests until timeout,

from a logical point of view, what may be the problem here ?

note: UDP is a must in this application so i cant just ignore it.

Comment: You used `udp` tag. If you are well using udp to send request, I suggest you to use TCP

Comment: well, the coap protocol is designed to be used with UDP, yes i can test with TCP and i did, but no response either.

Comment: Ok, so maybe with tracert/traceroute you can define issue

Comment: i tested with traceroute, but what am i supposed to see?

Comment: i want to add that when testing with TCP the server respond with RST message.

Comment: It's to be sure that you can access to server. Such as your update, the issue come from UDP. If you don't know the difference between UDP and TCP, I suggest you to check it. But, why do you must use UDP ?

Comment: as mentioned in the [rfc7252 of CoAP protocol](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7252#section-1.1) its a main feature of CoAP to use UDP binding, thats why i want to work with udp.
.

Comment: Do you have access to the coap-server logs? If so, do they contain log messages on receiving data? Also, did you try to run that coap-server maybe just on raspberry PI? I would first try to find out, if your request really reaches the coap-server.

Comment: AFAIK, using telnet to test a UDP server doesn't work.

Comment: thank you for the replies, actually i solved the problem, it was a configuration error on the server side!